# SQL Create a new column with if/else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on this task for way too long and I'm still stuck. What I need to do is, working on database AdventureWorks2014, retrieve CustomerIDs and Average of orders they made (all customers of course). My problem begins when I try to insert another column (called Valuable), that is supposed to have values:

- 'Y' if CustomerOrders > 10*AverageOfOrders and
- 'N' if CustomerOrders    < 10*AverageOfOrders.

I should use CTE, that's not that important though. I did it with CASE statement, yet I keep getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

If anyone could explain to me what am I doing wrong, that would be amazing. Below is my code:

```
WITH CustID AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(CustomerID) AS "NrOfOrdersPerCustomer"
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY CustomerID
),
AvgNr AS
(
SELECT AVG("NrOfOrdersPerCustomer") AS "AvgNrOfOrders"
FROM CustID
),
Joint AS
(
SELECT CustID.CustomerID, 'NULL' AS "Valuable", CustID."NrOfOrdersPerCustomer", AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders", 10*AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders" AS "MultipliedBy10"
    CASE 
    WHEN "NrOfOrdersPerCustomer" > "MultipliedBy10" THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
    FROM CustID, AvgNr
    END
)
SELECT * FROM Joint;
```

Comment: Mysql <> SQL Server (based on CTE and AdventureWorks2014)

Comment: `..AS "MultipliedBy10",..` -- Missing comma here

Comment: You don't put a FROM clause inside a CASE expression.

Comment: Also `..FROM CustID, AvgNr
    END..` should be `..END  FROM CustID, AvgNr..`

Comment: You should get out of the habit of wrapping column names in double quotes. If you have special characters or reserved words as object/column names you should wrap them in [] instead. And is it intentional to have a hard coded string with the value NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last CTE is wrong as

```
    Joint AS
    (
    SELECT CustID.CustomerID, 
    'NULL' AS "Valuable", 
    CustID."NrOfOrdersPerCustomer", 
    AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders", 
    10*AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders" AS "MultipliedBy10" <-- missing , here
        CASE 
        WHEN "NrOfOrdersPerCustomer" > "MultipliedBy10" THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N' <-- END should come here
        FROM CustID, AvgNr
        END <-- not here
    )
```

Your last CTE should look like

```
    Joint AS
    (
    SELECT CustID.CustomerID, 
    NULL AS "Valuable", 
    CustID."NrOfOrdersPerCustomer", 
    AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders", 
    10*AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders" AS "MultipliedBy10",
        CASE 
        WHEN "NrOfOrdersPerCustomer" > "MultipliedBy10" THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N' END AS Computed_Column
        FROM CustID, AvgNr
    )
```

Comment: I changed both, should be good now, thank you! The only error I get is that I haven't named the 5th column (I suppose it will be the one with Y/N values). Could you tell me how to improve the code to add column's name?

Answer (score 2):

There is already an answer that explains where your syntax errors are (missing comma and incorrect case expression), however, I thought I would just post an alternative solution that is much simpler:

```
WITH CustID AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(CustomerID) AS NrOfOrdersPerCustomer
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    GROUP BY CustomerID
)
SELECT  CustomerID,
        NrOfOrdersPerCustomer,
        AVG(NrOfOrdersPerCustomer) OVER() AS AvgNrOfOrders,
        AVG(NrOfOrdersPerCustomer) OVER() * 10 AS MultipliedBy10,
        CASE WHEN NrOfOrdersPerCustomer >  AVG(NrOfOrdersPerCustomer) OVER() * 10 THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N' 
        END AS Valuable
FROM    CustID;
```

This leverages the use a window function - `AVG(NrOfOrdersPerCustomer) OVER()` - meaning you can get the average of all customers without having to do a separate subquery. I have also removed quote marks from your aliases, for no other reason that they are not necessary unless your alias contains special characters, and I find them quite distracting, especially when not used consistently.

Comment: It appears that empty `OVER()` clauses didn't show up until SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @siride That's not true, I have been using empty `OVER()` clauses for years. [Here is an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6366) on SQL Server 2008 with an empty `OVER()` clause that works fine. An over clause is only required if the window function requires an order (`ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()` etc), or if you want to make an aggregate function cumulative.

Comment: @GarethD: I didn't see it in the documentation for 2008R2, and I had never used it before, so I wanted to put a warning out. It's good to know that it does work, as that will save me some slight annoyance in my own code!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `SELECT` line after `AS "MultipliedBy10"`, you need a comma. Also, your `CASE` statement is out of order at the end. `END` needs to be before the `FROM` statement. Corrected below:

```
WITH CustID AS
(
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(CustomerID) AS "NrOfOrdersPerCustomer"
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY CustomerID
),
AvgNr AS
(
SELECT AVG("NrOfOrdersPerCustomer") AS "AvgNrOfOrders"
FROM CustID
),
Joint AS
(
SELECT CustID.CustomerID, 'NULL' AS "Valuable", CustID."NrOfOrdersPerCustomer", AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders", 10*AvgNr."AvgNrOfOrders" AS "MultipliedBy10",
    CASE 
    WHEN "NrOfOrdersPerCustomer" > "MultipliedBy10" THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
    END
    FROM CustID, AvgNr

)
SELECT * FROM Joint;
```